# Unable to Play Video or Media related Files in Testcafe with Javascript

Tags: browser, automation, testcafe

Video Related scripts are not getting played using testcafe.

1. Click on Play button - Success
2. Play video - (It is just loading)

Is there any workaround to make video play using testcafe?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your case with this test:

```js
fixture`Fixture`
.page`https://www.devexpress.com/products/testcafestudio/`;

 

test('test', async (t) => {
    await t.switchToIframe('iframe')
    await t.click('.ytp-large-play-button.ytp-button.ytp-large-play-button-red-bg')
    await t.debug();
})
```

It works fine. Please share a simple sample. If you don't want to share your example here, you can do it with [a template on GitHub](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=TYPE%3A%20bug&template=bug_report.yaml). Try to follow [this instruction](https://testcafe.io/402636/faq#how-to-create-a-minimal-working-example-when-you-submit-an-issue) when creating an example.